# When running 'bundle install', bundler tries to install gem that is already installed locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Had some trouble with bundler trying to install the 'nokogiri' gem, so we went ahead and installed it manually with 'gem install nokogiri' - this was within an RVM ruby, and installed with native extensions.

Now, when running 'bundle install', it appears that bundle still tries to install nokogiri!  I've seen it said that when bundle runs, it checks locally for gems first, why might this not be happening?

UPDATE:

We are using Capistrano to deploy, and when i override the 'bundle:install' task to just run 'gem list --local', i get the following output:

```
  * executing "gem list --local"
    servers: ["myServer"]
    [myServer] executing command
 ** [out :: myServer] actionmailer (3.2.3, 3.0.11, 2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer] actionpack (3.2.3, 3.0.11, 2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer] activemodel (3.2.3, 3.0.11)
 ** [out :: myServer] activerecord (3.2.3, 3.0.11, 2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer] activeresource (3.2.3, 3.0.11, 2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer] activesupport (3.2.3, 3.0.11, 2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer] bundler (1.0.22, 1.0.21 ruby)
 ** [out :: myServer] capistrano (2.12.0)
 ...
 ** [out :: myServer] nokogiri (1.4.3.1)
 ...
    command finished in 863ms
```

and since, in our Gemfile, the require looks like:

```
gem "nokogiri", "= 1.4.3.1"
```

it looks to me like the right gem version is installed.  But when going back to standard 'bundle:install' task, the output includes:

```
  * executing "cd /path/to/releases/20120619165617 && bundle install --gemfile /path/to/releases/20120619165617/Gemfile --path /path/to/shared/bundle"
    servers: ["myServer"]
    [myServer] executing command
 ** [out :: myServer] Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
 ** [out :: myServer] Using rake (0.9.2.2)
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] Using activesupport (2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] Using rack (1.0.1)
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] Using actionpack (2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] Using actionmailer (2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] Using activerecord (2.3.5)
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] Using activeresource (2.3.5)
 ...
 ** [out :: myServer] Installing nokogiri (1.4.3.1)
 ** [out :: myServer] with native extensions
 ** [out :: myServer]
 ** [out :: myServer] ←[33mGem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: myServer]
```

Comment: No, but how would that be any different from system gems?  Will bundler find gems locally if they are in a gemset where it would not find them installed on the system?

Comment: Are you sure that the version you installed is suitable as match for the one bundler needs?
Check on Gemfile...