# Problems creating Gemfile on Windows, Deploying to Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm converting a number of applications to use Bundler, and i've seen it said that best practices is to check Gemfile.lock into versioning.  But i (and other devs on the team) work on Windows, whereas deployment on the central development/testing server and production is Linux.

From what i've found, it seems impossible with any substantial gem use to bundle on Windows and expect the Gemfile.lock to successfully deploy to a Linux environment.

The setup we are trying now is to commit Gemfile to versioning, and then execute 'bundle install' on deployment (with bundler/capistrano).  It's painful though ([bundler trying to install gems that are already installed locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019742/when-running-bundle-install-bundler-tries-to-install-gem-that-is-already-inst), permissions issues on installation), and i just want to make sure we're not going down the wrong road?

Comment: The question is more about whether not versioning Gemfile.lock is a good decision, no?

Answer (score 1):

Bundler allows creating groups based on platforms. Have you tried using that? We were able to maintain a non trivial Rails application on windows and linux using this approach.

eg:

```
platforms :ruby do
  linux compatible gems
end

platforms :mswin do
  windows compatible gems
end
```

Comment: Using this approach would allow versioning the Gemfile.lock, right? But i'm wondering how the Gemfile gets built (tracking down which gems go into each 'platforms' block), and then 'bundle install' could get executed on either platform and it would create a Gemfile.lock that would cover both?

Comment: Yes, this would allow you to version the Gemfile.lock. I dont know gory details, but it will generate just one Gemfile.lock, and based on whatever platform you are currently on, make sure those gems are installed.

Comment: Trying this route, but i feel like i'm missing something obvious.  For the 'nokogiri' gem, for example, there is a different version that gets used for Windows ('nokogiri (1.4.3.1-x86-mingw32)' is what shows up in Gemfile.lock), but using the 'platforms' technique just results in 'nokogiri' being listed in both platform groups, the windows version being what's stored in 'vendor/cache', and 'Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory. .. Could not find nokogiri-1.4.3.1 in any of the sources' in the failure output on deploying.  Do i need to 'bundle package' both platforms?

Comment: Can you remember how you got around this? Experiencing the same hurdle now!